# Access violation when pointer is not pointing to NULL

Tags: c++, pointers, error-handling, runtime, access-violation

This small code is causing a runtime error saying "Access Violation".
I read about it online which says that when a pointer is pointing to NULL, its value cannot be changed.
But that didn't solve the problem.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int max=3;
struct node
{
    char *ptr;
}*start, *current = start;

void init()
{
    current->ptr = (char*)malloc(max*sizeof(char)); //ERROR IN THIS LINE. 
}
void add(char page)
{
    char *c;
    c = current->ptr;
        if (page == *c)
            cout << "Yes";
        else
            cout << "No";
}
void main()
{
    init();
    add('a');
    cin >> max;
}
```

Comment: You need to make the pointers point to something that can be written to. Currently, they point to, for all intents and purposes, random locations.

Comment: @juanchopanza when I make pointers point a dynamically allocated space, will it not point to a garbage value at that position?

Comment: No, it will point to a dynamically allocated memory segment you can write to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code dump happens because you are accessing a pointer which is not initialized .
"current" should be initialized to a valid memory location before trying the De - referencing it .
more cleaner code would be

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int max=3;
struct node
{
    char *ptr;
};

struct node* start = new node();
struct node* current = start;

void init()
{
    current->ptr = (char*)malloc(max*sizeof(char)); //ERROR IN THIS LINE. 
}
void add(char page)
{
    char *c;
    c = current->ptr;
        if (page == *c)
            cout << "Yes";
        else
            cout << "No";
}
void main()
{
    init();
    add('a');
    cin >> max;
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me clear this concept: A pointer will always point to a value. If we use malloc, it will allocate a space and makes pointer refer that. else the pointer can be made to point somewhere else. Then what is the significance of node *start=new node(); NEW NODE() specifically.

Comment: A pointer un initialized points to a location which can be anything . accessing that will cause program to coredump as you are attempting to read or write the memory you dont have acess to . By new node() we are allocating memory from heap and assigning it to the ptr .

Answer (score 2):

This

```
struct node
{
    char *ptr;
}*start, *current = start;
```

not creates node struct, only pointer. So "current" is not initialized.
Change to

```
struct node
{
    char *ptr;
}start, *current = &start;
```

or add in main() or in init() correct memory allocation

```
current = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Comment: `current` isn't NULL here. It has an undetermined value.

Comment: I am not sure but I think there is GCC option to set should global memory be filled with zeros or not.

Comment: Oops, I hadn't realised the variables were global. Sorry about that! The pointers are zero initialized according to the C++ standard, so your first answer was correct. My bad.

Comment: current = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
is okay, but i want a char pointer to point the first byte (first char) of the memory allocated by malloc in node.

Comment: Try this `char *char_pointer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(node));`or `char *char_pointer = (char*) current`

Comment: what i want to do is, input `max` from user. Then continuously enter characters until the input is 'e'. The inputs (unless input!= 'e') will be in bunch of `max` characters. If max is three, there will be characters in groups of 3, each group will form a node. and so on.. hope i was clear enough!

Comment: @Srujan Barai , have I answered your initial question "Access violation when pointer is not pointing to NULL"? If yes - please accept my answer and post new question if you need additional help.